# AWS Amplify/Cognito- a way to set TOTP MFA on first time user login only

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, totp

I'm setting up an authentication where MFA is not optional, which means from the very first login attempt after registration, the user will be asked to set up MFA (in this case I will be using Time Based One Time Passcode, or TOPT). For this, I can see that following steps would be reasonable:

1)Get user information via the login form - `Auth.signUp()`

2)Determine from the user data retrieved in step 1) whether TOPT-based MFA is set for the user already. If not, go to step 3) or else step 4)

3)If TOPT is not set, redirect to a form where a QRCode will be generated in order to set up this MFA feature. After verifying the code, log the user in.

4)If TOPT is set, ask for the passcode. After verifying, log the user in.

My dilemma: It seems I cannot get the information in Step 2), i.e, whether TOPT-based MFA is set for the user already without the user already being authenticated. The flag `challengeName` retrieved in the payload via `Auth.signUp()` in step 1) only gives me info on whether MFA is enabled or not (`'MFA_SETUP'`), and not whether TOTP-based MFA has been set up already. For that, the method `Auth.getPreferredMFA()` is what would do the trick, but it only works if the user object being passed to it represents an authenticated (or already logged in) user. Is there a way to determine if TOTP MFA is set up for a user trying to log in (but not logged in yet)?

Also, any other solutions to tackle this problem would be welcome. There must be somebody out there who has run into the same scenario I have, where MFA is mandatory from the first log in itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. If the MFA is required, I open up a modal to get QR code displayed and setup the mfa for the user.

code: "NotAuthorizedException"
message: "Invalid session for the user."
name: "NotAuthorizedException"

But getting this error because the user hasn't logged in and created any access token yet.

My idea of solving this is actually logging in the user but making their permissions to not go beyond the SetupMFA screen so they only gain some permissions when they have completed the setup.

Have you made any progress yourself? I'd like to hear any solutions.

Comment: You are passing the same session or accessToken from the login, try to pass the session token received along with the secret key received from associate_software_token, to the validate_software_token.